# Why does the 9-bit address of the d-format in LEGv8 mean a register can load a doubleword of 2^8 bytes of the address in the base register Rn?

Tags: cpu-architecture

My textbook tells me that "the 9-bit address [of instruction format d-format] means a load register instruction can load any doubleword within a region of +/- 2^8 or 256 bytes of the address in the base register Rn." But why is it +/- 2^8 bytes and not +/- 2^9 bytes, since there are 9 bits in the address? And why is it +/- and not just +, since I doubt there can be a negative address? Or is the address signed but the Rn and Rt bits aren't?

Comment: The sign takes another bit. And certainly you can have addresses that are less than the value in Rn.

Comment: But then how can there be negative addresses, @RaymondChen? And are the address bits the only ones that are signed?

Comment: If Rn is 96 and the offset is -32, then the resulting address is 64, which is positive.